# MySQL Union situation

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to learn databases (specifically MySQL) and I am going over the questions within the textbook I have purchased (there is no solution manual provided). I have implemented part A of a question but I am confused how I would do part B. Part B requires getting the same result as Part A except using a UNION. I was wondering if someone could explain?

Thanks in Advance

Part A answer in my opinion:

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(City) from country LEFT OUTER JOIN city 
ON city.CountryId = country.CountryId group by Country;
```

Part B: Write the query from Part A as a UNION?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c1.countrynm,count(c2.citynm) 
from country c1 
join city c2
on c2.countryid=c1.countryid
group by c1.countrynm
union select countrynm,0 from country where 7=3;

mysql> select c1.countrynm,count(c2.citynm)
-> from country c1
-> join city c2
-> on c2.countryid=c1.countryid
-> group by c1.countrynm
-> union select countrynm,0 from country where 7=3;
+-----------+------------------+
| countrynm | count(c2.citynm) |
+-----------+------------------+
| France    |                2 |
| Germany   |                1 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mind explaining what C1, countrynm, c2, and citynm are in relation to my query from part A? Will accept. Thanks

Comment: Specifically what is "where 7=3"?

Comment: was kind of a joke Alex. I could not figure it out. where 7=3 mean return nothing cuz they are not equal. searched high and low. would love to know the answer to this one. c1 and c2 are aliases.

Comment: those were column names in my table.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select country from country group by country
 union
select count(city) from city group by city
```

while using "union" you will not get result in seperate column.You will get result in same column

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. With respect, I am not sure that is correct because it puts within one table. Based on other examples I've seen, I think what they meant was putting it into one table but with separate columns (Like you mentioned). Do you know how to do this? Thanks!